# How to block everything with IPTABLES?

Tags: linux, iptables, linux-kernel

I would like to block **everything** EXCEPT SSH/FTP/HTTP/POSTFIX and MySQL.

With "everything" I mean all the other ports, block pings etc etc.

Answer (score 7):

I'm guessing you mean incoming connections (the INPUT chain), and not forwarded ones (as in a router). Also I take postfix means just SMTP (25).

```
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -F INPUT

for port in 21 22 25 80 3306
do
  iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport $port -j ACCEPT
done

iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -P INPUT DROP
```

Test your FTP connection in particular, you may need to enable `ip_conntrack_ftp` for it to work correctly without modifying the client settings.

Comment: you can also chain them onto one line if you wish: iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --mport 21,22,25,80,3306 -j ACCEPT

Comment: +1 You could probably do with a `iptables -F INPUT` otherwise you may be building on any pre-existing INPUT rules which the OP may not want.

Comment: @Iain - you're right, thanks! @Squeeb - you're right too, thanks for the pointer - I prefer the for loop though if there aren't many rules around as it enables you to get per-port statistics easily on `iptables -nvL`. Do you know if there's a way to get that using multiport?

Comment: If you are on a Redhat-based machine, run `service iptables save` after the above steps to make the rules persistent (survive reboot etc.)

Comment: I'd also suggest replacing the last line with `iptables -A INPUT -j DROP` or even `iptables -A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited` instead of `-P DROP`.  In practice, setting the INPUT chain default policy to "DROP" is a sure-fire way to lock yourself out of the machine if you flush the rules by accident (easy to do when experimenting and setting up your firewall -- including if you run `iptables -F` as suggested earlier :))

Comment: @jmtd: thanks for you comments. I see your point against -P DROP, but I'm not certain on this matter. I once had a server running with no rules at all for more than a month because a member of the admin team accidentally deleted the catch-all rule. A policy change is more likely to be noticed earlier, as the chain header stands out. A minor point, I'm sure, and a matter of preference probably. I tend to think of `iptables -F INPUT` as a dangerous command you have to triple-check before running anyway, akin to `rm -rf *`, `reboot`, `mkfs.ext3` and the like.

Comment: Motivated by this discussion I've posted a new question, perhaps there are some reasons for or against either option that we're missing: http://serverfault.com/questions/267765/iptables-change-policy-or-use-catch-all-rule